# Adding numbers together as a result of an if statement

Tags: php, string, if-statement

So I'm looking to add numbers to a string as a result of an if statement. 
For example:

```
a = 2;
b = 1;

if($a == 2) {
    $total + 1;
}

if($b == 1) {
    $total + 1;
}

echo $total;
```

Obviously, these aren't my if statements but if they were to work then I would like $total to = 2? This seems sort of simple but I can't work it out?

Comment: So, you want to increase the value of the string by adding an integer? Then you have to first change the string into an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** it is simple as you said.

```
$a = 2; // use $ to initialize 
$b = 1;
$total =0; // define a total var to take changes 
  if($a == 2) {
     $total += 1;// asign changes to total with = sign
    }
     if($b == 1) {
     $total += 1;// asign changes to total with = sign
    }
    echo $total;// will give you 2
```

[Live demo](https://eval.in/1043416)

Comment: The OP said, that he want's to add the numbers to a string. So, this doesn't work for what the OP wants.

Comment: @Geshode : he said `I would like $total to = 2`

Comment: And in the first sentence he wrote `I'm looking to add numbers to a string`.

Comment: @Geshode : Yes you are right but he didn't use any string here?  Let us wait for his comment?

Comment: Yea so I'm looking to make this be dynamic since these are if statements I only want to add to the number if the if statement is triggered if that makes sense. Sorry for being unclear, but I think this should work, I'm going to add it to my code and give it a run, thanks for the help @C2486